# Assigning word from text file to array

Tags: arrays, vb.net

```
person1 bob
person2 george
person3 tom
```

This is a project on VB. I am attempting to read off a text file such as the above and assign the second word on each line to an array. For example, `array(1)` would be `"bob"`, `array(2)` would have `"george"`, and `array(3)` would have `"tom"`. I am currently having trouble with assigning to arrays as my current output for `array(1)` is:

```
bob
george
tom
```

My current attempt is:

```
Dim FileName As String = "*snip*"
Dim FileReader As StreamReader = File.OpenText(FileName)
Dim FileLine As String = FileReader.ReadLine()
For x = 1 To 18
    Dim players() As String = FileLine.Split(New Char() {" "c})
    FileLine = FileReader.ReadLine()
    Console.WriteLine(players(1))
    count = count + 1
Next
```

I'm a total noob, please treat me well.

Comment: If there's always a space between the two words your can use a `String.Split()` for each line in the file. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can i provide you a much simpler way using LINQ?

```
Dim resultArray = File.ReadLines(FileName).
   Select(Function(l) l.Split({" "c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Last().Trim()).
   ToArray()
```

If a line could contain more than two "words" you could use `ElementAtOrDefault(1)` instead of `Last` to access the second one (if available, otherwise it's `Nothing`).

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub GetPeople()

    ' use List instead of Array as you won't have to know 
    ' the length of the array before declaring it.
    Dim personList As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)

    ' this holds the path to your file
    Dim fname As String

    ' will hold the name of the person
    Dim personName As String

    fname = "[your file path here]"

    Dim reader As System.IO.StreamReader
    reader = New IO.StreamReader(fname)
    Dim line As String
    While (Not reader.EndOfStream)
        line = reader.ReadLine()

        ' after you read a line, you call the GetPersonName function
        personName = GetPersonName(line)
        personList.Add(personName)
    End While

    reader.Close()

    ' the names you are interested in are in personList now:
    dim i as long
    for i = 0 to personList.Count - 1
         Console.WriteLine(personList(i))
    next i
End Sub

Function GetPersonName(lineText As String) As String
    Dim Result As String
    Dim stringLength As Long
    Dim spaceIndex As Long
    spaceIndex = lineText.IndexOf(" ")
    stringLength = (lineText.Count - spaceIndex) - 1
    Result = lineText.Substring((spaceIndex + 1), stringLength)
    Return Result
End Function
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this and everything worked. Thanks heaps for your contributions guys.

```
Dim resultArray = File.ReadLines(FileName).
    Select(Function(l) l.Split({" "c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Last().Trim()).
    ToArray()
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex is admittedly an advanced concept, so you may want to hold off on learning it until you gain more experience, but, just so you're aware of it, it can be a powerful option when you need to do string parsing, replacements, and validation.  Here's an example of how this could be done with Regex:

```
Dim result() As String = Regex.
    Matches(File.ReadAllText(FileName), "^\s*\w+\s+(\w+)\s*$", RegexOptions.Multiline).
    Cast(Of Match).Select(Function(match) match.Groups(1).Value).ToArray()
```

The real power, here, is the extra validation being performed.  Only lines that exactly match the regex pattern will be processed.  Also, by specifying a pattern, it's easier to adjust or improve it in the future.  Here's an explanation of the pattern (`^\s*\w+\s+(\w+)\s*$`):

- `^` - Only strings that start at the beginning of a line will match
- `\s*` - Any number of whitespace characters at the beginning of the line will be allowed

  - `\s` - This is a special character class which matches any whitespace character
  - `*` - The character class will match zero or more characters in a row
- `\w+` - Matching strings must then contain a word

  - `\w` - A special character class which matches any word character
  - `+` - The character class will match one or more characters in a row
- `\s+` - The first word must be followed by one or more whitespace characters
- `(\w+)` - There must be a second word.  The parentheses create a capturing group.  In this case, capturing group signifies the portion of the match that we want to grab (i.e. we don't care about the rest of the matching line, just the second word).
- `\s*` - The second word may be followed by any number of whitespace characters
- `$` - Signifies the end of the line.  By putting this in the pattern, it makes it so matches must fill an entire line.  In other words, only lines containing exactly two words will be processed.

Regex is a common tool that you'll see in many languages, software development tools and IDEs (e.g. Visual Studio search/replace, SSMS search/replace, Notepad++, grep), so it's worth the time to get to know it once you feel ready to take the plunge.

Regarding your original question, however, everyone answering seems to have avoided actually helping you to understand how to populate an array.  The real answer is, it's not that simple because arrays are inherently fixed length.  You can technically "resize" them in VB (using `ReDim`), but it's inefficient, old-school, and ugly.  If you need to add an unknown number of items to an array, one at a time, it's best to use a `List(Of T)` object.  For instance:

```
Dim result As New List(Of String)()
Dim line As String = Nothing
Do
    line = reader.ReadLine()
    If line IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim fields() As String = line.Split({" "c})
        result.Add(fields(1))
    End If
Loop While line IsNot Nothing
```

If you then need to convert the list to a fixed-length array, you can do this:

```
Dim arr() As String = result.ToArray()
```

If, however, you definitely know the exact number of items you have, it's possible (though still generally discouraged) to set the size of the array ahead of time and then fill each item in a loop:

```
Dim result(18) As String
For x = 0 To 17
    Dim fields() As String = line.Split({" "c})
    result(x) = fields(1)
    line = reader.ReadLine()
Next
```

I say it's discouraged because it's more brittle, harder to read, and it's unnecessary, even when factoring performance.  If you know the size, and performance is a problem, you could still use a `List` and just specify the size in the constructor to pre-allocate the memory:

```
Dim result As New List(Of String)(18)
```

However, as you've seen, when it's possible to write your code in a more declarative style, using LINQ, it's generally preferred by most people over any of these imperative styles.